# Django querysets and foreign keys

Tags: python, django

I've got a reddit-like application. There are "posts" and people vote on them up or down. In my template I list all the posts and I want to be able to indicate whether the person has already voted on a post or not.

It's a little confusing because I'm passing my queryset full of posts to the template but as I iterate through each post to display it I also want to know if there is an existing vote or not.

Here is some code:

```
class Submission(models.Model):
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=200)

class Vote(models.Model):
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submission = models.ForeignKey(Submission)
    vote_value = models.FloatField()

class SubmissionListView(ListView):
    model = Submission
    queryset = Submission.objects.extra(select={'total': 'IFNULL((SELECT SUM(vote_value) ' + \
        'FROM submissions_vote ' + 'WHERE submissions_vote.submission_id = ' + 'submissions_submission.id), ' + \
        '0)'}).order_by('-total')
    paginate_by = 5
```

Ok so you can see I'm doing a queryset extra() because I want to sum up all the votes for each post and display the total on the page. I think this is the most efficient way to do this.

But if the user who is viewing the page has made a vote for a particular submission I need to convey that information to the template somehow. I know I can loop through each vote object in the template and figure it out there but that seems really inefficient. I've been reading about chaining querysets.. is that what I need to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add another `extra` select:

```
queryset = Submission.objects.extra(
    select={'total': 'IFNULL((SELECT SUM(vote_value) ' + \
        'FROM submissions_vote ' + 'WHERE submissions_vote.submission_id = ' + \
        'submissions_submission.id), ' + '0)',
    'has_voted': 'CASE WHEN %d IN (SELECT voter_id FROM submissions_vote WHERE ' + \
        'submissions_vote.submission_id = submissions_submission.id) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END'
    }, select_params=(self.request.user.pk,)).order_by('-total')
```

I know this isn't the prettiest solution. I usually try to not write custom sql too often, but I can't think of anything better. Would love to know what you end up doing.

EDIT: since you need access to self.request, you need to override the `get_queryset` method:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Submission.objects.extra(
    select={'total': 'IFNULL((SELECT SUM(vote_value) ' + \
        'FROM submissions_vote ' + 'WHERE submissions_vote.submission_id = ' + \
        'submissions_submission.id), ' + '0)',
    'has_voted': 'CASE WHEN %d IN (SELECT voter_id FROM submissions_vote WHERE ' + \
        'submissions_vote.submission_id = submissions_submission.id) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END'
    }, select_params=(self.request.user.pk,)).order_by('-total')
```

Do that instead of the `queryset` variable

Comment: Mmm.. I like your idea but I can't seem to access self.request.user.pk at that point. Probably because self isn't available at this point?

Comment: Ah my bad. I didn't realize where you were defining queryset. I have edited my answer to fix that.

Comment: Yes that seems to work. Except I actually need the "vote_value" field to be returned so I can tell if the vote is up or down. I tried to say then select voter_id, vote_value..... then vote_value else 0 but that didn't work.

Comment: Does this work? `'SELECT vote_value FROM submissions_vote WHERE submissions_vote.submission_id = submissions_submission.id AND submissions_vote.voter_id = %d'` for the `'has_voted'` select? (which needs to be renamed now.) I'm just not sure what will happen if there are no results.

Comment: Yes, that's what I just ended up doing and it worked. I did have to rename the has_voted because of the underscore of course, bad variable name choice. It's all working now, thanks so much for your help.